# Spring security's @EnableWebSecurity vs oauth's @EnableResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a system using Spring Boot, Angular 2, Spring OAuth 2 where I have implemented security using `@EnableWebSecurity` and implemented oauth using `@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableAuthorizationServer` in the same application.

Following are the implemented classes:

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("username").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","USER")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1200).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(6000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('USER')");
    }

}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("USER");
    }
}
```

All the url following the **/public** are accessible by any users; it's correct. The urls following **/private/** are secured by both `ResourceServerConfig` and `SecurityConfig`, therefore it's not accessible to anonymous users.

When I request `access_token` from authorization server using `grant_type=password`, I get the `access_token` which I use to access the secured resources by appending the `access_token` as the parameter. But still the resources are not available and I get the response as below:

```
localhost:8080/private/user/test/?access_token=92f9d86f-83c4-4896-a203-e21976d4cfa2    

{
    "timestamp": 1495961323209,
    "status": 403,
   "error": "Forbidden",
   "message": "Access Denied",
   "path": "/private/user/test/"
}
```

But when I remove the `antMatchers` from `SecurityConfig.configure(HttpSecurity)`, the resources are no longer secured even if the `ResourceServerConfig.configure(HttpSecurity)` is securing the patters.

My questions:

- Is there anything I need to perform in `ResourceServerConfig` so as to grant access to authorized users from the resource server?
- What is difference between `@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableWebSecurity`? Do I need to implement both in this application? *(I couldn't find any good answers for this questions)*

Comment: Do you get any solution for the above?

Answer (score 0):

Your private resource is well secured, but the *access_token* obtained is not passed the correct way to the server.

You have to pass it as header of the request with

```
 Authorization: Bearer 92f9d86f-83c4-4896-a203-e21976d4cfa2
```

or as curl command:

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 92f9d86f-83c4-4896-a203-e21976d4cfa2"
```